# I removed x permission from everything, can I recover my error?

Tags: server, permissions, data-recovery

So I made a stupid error in a command and ran `chmod -x -R /`
I can not run any commands that I can tell.

Is there a way to recover? workaround to get system functioning again?

I have backups but did not make one since some changes were made in the past week. Yes, dumb mistake.
I am currently SSH into the remote server. I do not want to disconnect unless I have to. I am using aws services.

Comment: Is there not a way to mount another volume to run chmod application on this botched volume?

Comment: Yes you could boot a 'live' environment and `mount` your partition and change settings; but knowing what to reset back to +x is ???    I wrote a script once to copy permissions from another box over to the box I'd mucked up permissions for, and the exercise was well worth it knowledge wise - but a re-install would have been faster (script was quick/easy; but testing it before I was willing to 'trust' the results was a long time!)

Comment: Yes, i just attempted this and was able to give `x` back to everything. but that is also an issue now. additionally, i am not able to access with SSH on port 22 when change things back to the original volume, maybe a file with `x` that shouldnt have it? My issue is my backup is a little outdated. I believe for the most part only `var/www` files were edited since the backup.  would you happen to have this script? I currently have the messed up volume(the one i need) mounted as /mnt/oldserver .

Comment: @guiverc is this the script? refer to the first answer:    https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/1323/i-accidentally-chmod-r-x-on-a-directory-how-do-i-restore-the-correct-permissi

Comment: No; I wrote the script myself, it just walked a tree for my *alternate-box* & from each file/directories `stat` output copied & overwrote permissions on my *to-be-fixed* box (for the same file/directory). ie. made the *to-be-fixed* box have same permissions as my '*new-install*' box; where you'd use your *restored-backup*.

Comment: @guiverc sounds like a useful tool, maybe you should re-write and market it. many use cases for replicated instances. i went ahead and just copied newer directories over to restored image. ill find out soon enough if i missed one. thanks again. also, go ahead and write up something about using the backup image, mounting, and chmod to access newer files to copy over. and ill mark as answered

Answer (score 0):

create to @Sorin:

Actually, it seems that you can run the loader directly and make chmod executable again without booting from something else: `/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 /usr/bin/chmod +x /usr/bin/chmod` Note that the loader may be located somewhere else, or for 32 bits it might be `/lib/ld-linux.so.2` instead. –